# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when click on button

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I added 2 views side by side. But I am getting `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` when I try to click on a button on the second view. If I switch the view with another view, then it performs well. But on a second view it won't.

```
UIViewController *AddDataViewController=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AddData"];
UIViewController *ShowDataViewController=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ShowData"];


CGRect Frame;

Frame.origin.x=0;
Frame.origin.y=0;
Frame.size=CGSizeMake(320, 250);

AddDataViewController.view.frame=Frame;

[self.scrollView2 addSubview:AddDataViewController.view];

CGRect Frame1;

Frame1.origin.x=320;
Frame1.origin.y=0;
Frame1.size=CGSizeMake(320, 250);

ShowDataViewController.view.frame=Frame1;

[self.scrollView2 addSubview:ShowDataViewController.view];
```

Error is:

2013-12-31 16:17:56.856 wheel_With_images[439:c07] *** -[ShowDataViewController performSelector:withObject:withObject:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x767de70

Comment: Please add the whole stack trace.

Comment: Have you double checked the viewcontroller identifier in the storyboard? i sense except the instantiate line other things will not make you crash?

Comment: I suggest you rename `Vc` variable like `addDataController` and `shwoDataController`.

Comment: I had checked so many time my viewController identifier are same. and I can access first view . Only problem is with second view..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You problem is that `AddDataViewController` and `ShowDataViewController` are deallocated after the method is executed. You have to add them as instance variables

**In .h file**

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIViewController *AddDataViewController;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIViewController *ShowDataViewController;
```

**In .m file**

```
self.AddDataViewController=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AddData"];
self.ShowDataViewController=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ShowData"];
```

Comment: Now it won't give error but it is not calling method that i wrote for it. It is calling method of button when I load ViewController separately with out adding it in scrollview

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand what you are trying to say ... What happen when you click on the button?

Comment: I had made modification in my code as you say. Now I am not getting error like "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" but I had write Action for button that are not called when I click on the button.

Comment: Did you check your IBAction? ... How did you assigned that method with the button action?

Comment: Ya I checked IBAction. I had also put breakpoint it stop application and redirect me for debugging but it redirect me to memory file in which all assembly lines are written .

Comment: Can you add screenshot for the storyboard connections and code of your IBAction method? ... Did you set the class of the viewController in the storyboard to be your view controller?